git rebase --update-refs diverged my branches
I've been using Stacked Pull-Requests to guide my team members through a feature development.
However, meanwhile some other developer merged his changes in develop so I had to rebase.
This was before rebase:
                 F3.1
                 /
     F2.1-F2.2-F2.3
     /
  F1.1
  /
DEV_1-DEV_2

My feature had three branches, F1, F2 and F3. My collegue pushed DEV_2. I wanted this:
                       F3.1
                       /
           F2.1-F2.2-F2.3
           /
        F1.1
        /
DEV_1-DEV_2

But after running
$ git checkout F3.1
$ git rebase --update-refs develop

I diverged, so I used
$ git push --force

from F3.1
And now I have
     F2.1-F2.2-F2.3
     /
  F1.1   F1.1-F2.1-F2.2-F2.3-F3.1
  /      /
DEV_1-DEV_2

I already reset it to previous structure, so that's not the problem. But it seems like I misunderstood --update-refs. I thought it would take care of exactly that by updating every ref from other branches?!

Just to be sure I understand, you had branch F1 point to commit F1.1, and branch F2 point to commit F2.3, right?

I have 3 Branches F1 (1 Commit F1,1), F2 (2 Commits F2.1, F2.2) and F3 (1 Commit F3.1). So yes, you are right

Just recreated your scenario with the same structure, and in my case F1, F2 and F3 all got updated.

Are F1, F2 and F3 all locally checked out, or just remote tracking branches, e.g., origin/F1?

What exactly did you do in what order? @joanis

checkout dev1, create f1 and make a commit, create f2 and make 3 commits, create f3 and make a commit, go back to dev to create commit dev2, go back to f3 and rebase with --update-refs.

The question about whether you have local F1 or remote origin/F1 is important: I'm pretty sure --update-refs would only change local branches, so please clarify which of these two options you have.

For what it's worth, if you do git rebase -i --update-refs <target> you'll see exactly what refs it's going to update in the todo list, before anything happens.

Thanks for your help. I will verify monday on work and write you back!

Thanks for the Help @joanis I figured out that the error was indeed the missing origin/

Based on the clarifications in the comments, the problem was that only locally checked out branches F1, F2, F3 would get updated, while the remote tracking branches origin/F1, origin/F2 and origin/F3 will not be modified.
In order to update the remote branches, and therefore the remote-tracking ones, you will need to checkout and update the local ones first, then push them.
For the git rebase --update-refs command to work as you wanted, you would have had to check out each branch locally first.
For example:
git checkout F1
git checkout F2
git checkout F3
git rebase --update-refs develop

will yield updated local branches F1, F2 and F3 than you can force push to origin, with all the usual caveats that people who are working on F1, F2 and F3 need to be aware of what you're doing and know how to rebase their own local work on the results.

Yeah, and force-push all 3 braches, not just the most-recent one, i.e. git push origin +F1 +F2 +F3
